# dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Permission denied

Tags: linux, debian, dmesg, sysctl

Since recently Debian has changed the default behavior for `dmesg` and I cannot use it simply from my local user.

```
% dmesg
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

Same goes for:

```
% cat /dev/kmsg                      
cat: /dev/kmsg: Operation not permitted
```

Starring at the bug tracker this lead to:

- [dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted](https://bugs.debian.org/842226)

How do I change this behavior back to the previous one, where local user are allowed to use dmesg. I could not find a particular group for it (eg. sudoers or something like that).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

So it was actually trivial, looking at the very last message from the bug report:

- [Re: Bug#842226: dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted](https://bugs.debian.org/842226#15)

> Part of the changelog from the aforementioned kernel:
>
> - security,printk: Enable SECURITY_DMESG_RESTRICT, preventing non-root   users reading the kernel log by default (sysctl:
>   kernel.dmesg_restrict)

So the solution is simply to run once:

```
% sudo sysctl kernel.dmesg_restrict=0
kernel.dmesg_restrict = 0
```

Then your local user can start using `dmesg` again. This apply to any user, instead of a group which I initially assumed.

Everything is back to what I wanted:

```
% dmesg|wc
   1307   11745   93652
```

and

```
% cat /dev/kmsg|head|wc
     10      82     857
```

And to make it persists across reboots, simply save it as conf file:

```
$ echo kernel.dmesg_restrict = 0 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/10-local.conf >/dev/null
$ cat /etc/sysctl.d/10-local.conf 
kernel.dmesg_restrict = 0
```

If you are on Ubuntu, for release 20.10 onwards there is already a line to persist this setting in `/etc/sysctl.d/10-kernel-hardening.conf`. After changing the file, to make the changes effective the user either needs to reboot or run `sudo service procps restart` .

Comment: Are you able to execute  this command: `cat /dev/kmesg` as a regular user?

Comment: It should be `/dev/kmsg` in the first comment that was a typo.

Comment: Easier to make it permanent by adding

`kernel.dmesg_restrict = 0`

to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.10, there is already a line for this in `/etc/sysctl.d/10-kernel-hardening.conf`. After changing the file, the user should run `sudo service procps restart` to allow dmesg viewing again.

Answer (score 0):

This does it for me.

```
chown root `which dmesg` 
chmod u+s `which dmesg`
```