# Why does dmesg need sudo if journalctl can access the same info without root?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, dmesg

These days, at least in Arch Linux (probably true for other distros too? [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390184/dmesg-read-kernel-buffer-failed-permission-denied)), `dmesg` needs `sudo`, otherwise it doesn't work:

```
$ dmesg
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

On the other hand, `journalctl` (from `systemd`) doesn't need `sudo`.

It feels odd because `journalctl` can access much of the same information (if not all) of `dmesg`.

**Does anyone know why one is restricted but the other isn't?** My installation is pretty vanilla, and I haven't made any custom changes to `sysctl` (`/etc/sysctl.d/`) and alike.

I've found a similar question outside of SE[2](https://www.reddit.com/r/ManjaroLinux/comments/dhfmk8/why_does_dmesg_need_sudo_if_journalctl_can_access/) however it doesn't have any replies.

Comment: https://man.archlinux.org/man/journalctl.1.en: "Members of the groups "systemd-journal", "adm", and "wheel" can read all journal files." `journalctl` clearly isn't a free-for-all, it's restricted too. Are you in one of those groups?

Comment: I have `journalctl` hints in my Stack Exchange profile, click on my userid below this comment.

Comment: Look at `ls -l $(type -p journalctl)`. Is it setuid? `man ls stat`.

Comment: @muru: Membership in the `systemd-journal` group would seem to be a requirement for system (or application) managers. `journalctl` is the new way of slicing and dicing log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`journalctl` access is indeed restricted to members of the following groups: `adm`, `systemd-journal`, `wheel` according to `man journalctl` and it's indeed the case for Fedora 33:

```
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal', 'wheel' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
```

As for `dmesg` its access is regulated by the sysctl variable, `kernel.dmesg_restrict` which at least in Fedora is set to 0, which means any local user can read the kernel log.

IMO, I see no reason to restrict access to `dmesg` while the system log may contain information which could allow to gain unauthorized access to the system.

Comment: By restricting, `dmesg` non-privileged users need to beg sysadmins to have a look. This is a nice vulnerability drama to appease bureaucracy.