# dmesg: klogctl: Operation not permitted

Tags: permissions, dmesg

I see the following error running dmesg in my Linux running on a embedded board.

```
/ # dmesg
dmesg: klogctl: Operation not permitted
```

As you see, I'm running as root. I am also aware of the question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390184/dmesg-read-kernel-buffer-failed-permission-denied). But when I issue the solution given there I get the following error:

```
/ # echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/dmesg_restrict
sh: write error: Operation not permitted
```

Any idea how should I get around with it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you specify the Linux distribution and hardware type used?

Comment: The Linux image is built using Yocto/OpenEmbedded. The hardware is Qualcomm RB5. It's really new hardware but I thought this issue is unrelated to the hardware I'm using.

Comment: [`klogctl(3)/syslog(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/klogctl.3#ERRORS)  documents the error. Maybe you are root with some privileges removed?. You can check with `grep ^Cap /proc/$$/status`. If you don't get 3 lines (out of 5) that have a lot of ffff at the end, then you should add the results in the question.

Comment: Or with embedded who knows: https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/EMBEDDED.html (but usually unavailable features are ENOSYS, not EPERM)